# CLion: Go to Header/Source menu includes QT MOC files

Tags: c++, qt, ide, clion, moc

CLion with a Qt library.

Then I'm using "Go to Header/Source" shortcut in any of my class inherited from QObject, I have this problem:

[image: screenshot]

It causes some inconvenience.

1. Extra "Enter" click to jump into a file.
2. Then I'm using code-generation options (alt + insert menu), for example "Generate definition for function ***", it can be generated inside of moc_filename.cpp file.

So, CLion considers every moc_filename.cpp file as a header's source.

I tried to find the answer in a Google and Jetbrains IDE documentation, but unsuccessfully. Maybe anyone encounters the same problem and find a solution? This problem is really annoying...

Thanks.